# CSS Variable Sometimes Is All Lowercase in Browser but Hump Case in the Variables.css File

Tags: css, asp.net

We have a web application and we just implemented CSS variables. The variables are defined in a `variables.css` file and are hump case in the file. When the user is on the same network where the website is hosted everything works fine. When the user is outside the network and hitting the web application from the internet the variables are sent to the browser in all lower case which does not apply the desired styling since the variable is hump case on the control (verified using Chrome debugger) but now lowercase in the variables sent to the browser. If I open the Chrome debugger and change the variable name back to the hump case version the styling is applied.

This is very strange behavior and I can't understand what could be causing the variables to be sent to the browser as all lower case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

variables.css:

```
:root {
    --primaryButtonBackgroundColor: #6c757d;
    --primaryButtonTextColor: white;
    --primaryButtonHoverBackgroundColor: #5a6268;
    --primaryButtonHoverTextColor: white;
}
```

ASP.NET Styling From Page (Chrome Debugger):

```
.btn-primary {
    background-color: var(--primaryButtonBackgroundColor) !important;
    color: var(--primaryButtonTextColor) !important;
```

Rendered Variables (Chrome Debugger):

```
:root {
    --primarybuttonbackgroundcolor: #6c757d;
    --primarybuttontextcolor: white;
    --primarybuttonhoverbackgroundcolor: #5a6268;
    --primarybuttonhovertextcolor: white;
}
```

Edit: We noticed that the variables.css file is the only css file we have that is being minified when looking at the sources using the Chrome Debugger as well but this only happens when outside the application server's network.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that they had some software (Imperva) monitoring their websites that auto minified CSS files and was changing the file before being sent to the browser.